# OutputDebugStringW function equivalent for Google Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there an equivalent to the [OutputDebugStringW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) for Google Chrome extensions? The problem with [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log), [console.debug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/debug), etc. is that there is no one place where you can see all of the output. There is one place where you can see the output from the content scripts, another place where you can see the output from the background service worker, and yet another place where you can see the output from the DevTools page. An equivalent to the [OutputDebugStringW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) would provide a single place where you can easily see all output from all parts of the extension and easily save all output to a log file.

Comment: No such thing. You can imitate it by sending a message from the content script and print it in background script's console.